# Запуск кода с github в IDEA

Tags: java, github, intellij-idea

Как правильно запустить прогу с git'a, не создавая новый проект в IDE?
Я скачал zip, в IDEA открыл папку, собрал, но запустить не получается (run не активный), и значки классов имеют красные кружки :) (Обычно -- синие кружки с буквой 'С')

**update:**

[image: введите описание изображения здесь]

[image: введите описание изображения здесь]
[image: введите описание изображения здесь]

Comment: а как ты открыл папку в Idea? там можно открыть либо файл либо проект

Comment: Я нажал Open, выделил папку и нажал Ok.

Comment: Обычно проекты собираются системой сборки. Для java используют чаще всего maven или gradle. Соответственно вам нужно импортировать в idea проект сосответствующего типа. Можете дать ссылку на github, так будет проще понять, какая система сборки используется?

Comment: Вот: https://github.com/compl/TicTacToe

Answer (score 4, accepted):

C помощью `File -> Open` можно открыть только проекты , подготовленные ранее в самой IDEA

Для того , чтобы запусить любой Java-проект , вам нужно проделать нехитрую последовательность действий по импорту проекта , чтобы IDEA могла создать свои рабочие файлы:

1. Распаковать архив с проектом в рабочую директорию IDEA
2. В IDEA : `File -> New -> Project from existing sources` - выбрать корневую папку проекта

Появится мастер импорта проекта в котором :

1. На первом экране выбираем : `Create project from existing sources`
2. Далее жмем `Next` , так как все значения по умолчанию , как правило , подходят , пока не дойдем до экрана `Please select project SDK` , где нужно выбрать желаемую версию компилятора Java (например 1.8 )
3. Далее опять жмем `Next` и в конце `Finish`

Теперь настраиваем конфигурацию запуска : `Run -> Edit Configuration`:

1. Нажимаем на `+` вверху слева , выбираем `Application`
2. В поле `Name:` в самом верху пишем название конфигурации , оно может быть произвольным
3. В поле `Main class:` выбираем стартовый класс , содержащий метод `main()` , IDEA предложит список подходящих.
4. Нажимаем `OK`

Импортирование проекта закончено .

Скриншоты:

[image: добавление метода main()]
[image: проект]

PS: Что касается именно [этого](https://github.com/compl/TicTacToe) проекта , то у меня для вас плохие новости , он в общих словах - НЕРАБОЧИЙ . Нет реализации некоторых классов и методов

Comment: Обновил вопрос. Но Main почему-то отображается как обычный файл. И добавить его не получается, как Main. (см. пикчу)

Comment: Я переименовал Main (см. пикчу) и сразу всё стало хорошо. Переименовал обратно в Main, и опять он отображает Main как обычный файл, а не класс. В чем может быть проблема?

Comment: Если это вам помогает , то измените название (рефакторингом) на то , которое считаете нужным - это не принципиально . У меня такой проблемы не появилось - смотрите скриншоты .

Answer (score 1):

Для того что бы иметь возможность собирать, необходимо открыть проект как... проект. Именно проект описывает как собирать приложение. Если проект нельзя открыть или импортировать то придется создать новый.

**Обновление**:

Возможно у Вас просто нету нужной конфигурации запуска.
Нажмите на Edit Configurations.

[image: Edit Configurations]

Затем добавьте необходимую:
[image: Edit Run Configurations]

Для запуска простого Java приложения обычно используется конфигурация `Application`.

Далее скорее всего понадобиться выбрать необходимый модуль и сохранить конфигурацию.

Comment: Я просто нажал Open, выделил папку и нажал Ok. Потом собрал.

Comment: Поздравляю, Вы открыли проект!

Comment: :/ Поздравлять нужно, когда проект запускается, а у меня в этом то и проблема.

Comment: Обновил ответ .